# Is it possible to have different value of static variable for every instance?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with some static variables and I want to create multiple independent instances of this class. Independent meaning, that they do not share values of these static variables.

Is there a way how to achieve this without refactoring said class?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for a static variable?  Since you want a different value in every instance, there must be a good reason why you are not looking at an instance variable.

Comment: The whole point of having `static` variables is precisely to have one instance of it per *AppDomain*. Your use case just seems the normal behavior of instance variables.

Comment: Why use static in the first place?

Comment: You keep saying that word `static`, I do not think it means what you think it means. That said, maybe use a map? That way you can have a single variable but it has multiple values. I'd just refactor it though.

Comment: I am not the author of the class with static variables and I would prefer not to change it, because it is an essential part of the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have a class with some static variables and I want to create multiple independent instances of this class.

In that case you just don't want static variables. `static` means "associated with the type rather than an instance of the type" - you just want instance variables.

That may mean changes elsewhere in your app, of course, but there's nothing you can do about that - or at least, any alternatives are going to be *much* more hacky than just taking the straightforward approach.

Comment: @Noxor: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28235493/3764814)'s one such *hacky* alternative, just in case you want to see how much *hacky* it can get ;-)

Comment: Thanks, using AppDomain was one of the options we thought about. I was just curious whether there is something more elegant.

Comment: @Noxor: Yes, the "elegant" approach is to avoid abusing static fields. "I want an independent field per instance" *screams* out for using instance fields. Bite the bullet, and use the language the way it was designed.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are shared among every instance of a type, so you need instance variables, that will solve your problem. so refactoring is needed.

Comment: It's not that they're "shared among every instance" - they're *completely independent* of instances. You might as well say they're "shared among all strings". "Shared among every instance" makes it sound like there needs to be at least *one* instance, whereas in reality they're just associated with the type itself.